# Pythagorean Triples in Assembly, Access violation writing location 0x00190000

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, access-violation, irvine32

I'm writing an assembly program that generates all possible Pythagorean triples, my problem is that after it runs for awhile I get this error:
 "Unhandled exception at 0x00403484 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00190000."

When I click on the error it takes me to my triple procedure
        (mov  A, eax)

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with this I don't know why it's okay to write to it the first 7 times, but come the 8th time there's an error.

```
TITLE Program 3 Pythagorean Triples         (main.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

myMessage BYTE "Here is a list of all possible Pythagorean Triples: ",0dh,0ah,0 
myX     BYTE " x: ",0               
myY     BYTE " y: ",0
myZ     BYTE " z: ",0
myU     DWORD ?
myV     DWORD ?
mytempX DWORD ?
mytempY DWORD ?
mytempZ DWORD ?


.code

 main PROC 
 mov    edx, OFFSET myMessage
 call   WriteString
 mov    myU, 2
 dowh1: mov    eax, myU
    and    eax, 1
    jnz    else1
    mov    myV, 1
    jmp    dowh2
 else1: mov    myV, 2
 dowh2: call   gcd
    cmp    eax, 1
    jne    else2
    mov    eax, myU
    mov    ebx, myV
    call   triple
    jmp    enddo2
else2:  add    myV, 2
    mov    eax, myV
    cmp    eax, myU
    jb     dowh2
enddo2: add    myU, 1
    mov    eax, myU
    cmp    eax, 10
    jb     dowh1 

exit
main ENDP
```

GCD Procedure

```
gcd  PROC A:DWORD, B:DWORD

     mov  eax, myU
     mov  A, eax
     mov  ebx, myV
     mov  B, ebx

while1:  mov  ebx, B
     cmp  ebx, 0
     jna  endwh1
     mov  eax, A
     mov  edx, 0
     div  B
     xchg edx, B
     mov  A, edx
     jmp  while1
endwh1:  mov  eax, A
     ret

     exit
gcd  ENDP
```

Triple Procedure

```
triple PROC U:DWORD, V:DWORD

    mov  eax, myU
    mov  U, eax
    mov  ebx, myV
    mov  V, ebx

    mov  eax, U
    mul  U
    mov  mytempX, eax
    mov  eax, V
    mul  V
    sub  mytempX, eax

    mov  eax, U
    mov  ecx, V
    mul  ecx
    add  eax, eax
    mov  mytempY, eax

    mov  eax, U
    mul  U
    mov  mytempZ, eax
    mov  eax, V
    mul  V
    add  mytempZ, eax

    mov  eax, mytempX
    cmp  eax, mytempY
    jna  ENDIF1
    mov  eax, mytempX
    xchg eax, mytempY
    mov  mytempX, eax

endif1: mov  edx, OFFSET myX
    call WriteString
    mov  eax, mytempX
    call WriteInt
    mov  edx, OFFSET myY
    call WriteString
    mov  eax, mytempY
    call WriteInt
    mov  edx, OFFSET myZ
    call WriteString
    mov  eax, mytempZ
    call WriteInt
    call CRLF
    ret

    exit
triple ENDP
END main
```

OUTPUT

```
 Here is a list of all possible Pythagorean Triples:
x: +3 y: +4 z: +5
x: +5 y: +12 z: +13
x: +8 y: +15 z: +17
x: +20 y: +21 z: +29
x: +12 y: +35 z: +37
x: +28 y: +45 z: +53
x: +16 y: +63 z: +65
```

PS. I hope I did everything right, this is my first time posting here.

Comment: You declared `gcd` and `triple` as taking 2 arguments each, but you don't pass any. Maybe you wanted to use `LOCAL` variables instead?

Comment: I had tried passing them using "INVOKE gcd, myU, myV" but it kept on saying that gcd wasn't defined.

Comment: You might need to move the `gcd` procedure to before `main` so that it is seen first, or declare a prototype using `PROTO`.

Comment: Thanks Jester, I switched to actually passing parameters and put the code before main and it worked.